# Refresh listView Items when a picture is loaded

Tags: android, listview, asynchronous, bitmap, notifydatasetchanged

On my App, I have a ListView which is populated thanks to an ArrayAdapter, a custom one. Each listView item contains an ImageView. Since the items are populated, I start to download every picture related to each listView item.
When I get the picture bitmap, I need to update the data of my adapter using **notifyDataSetChanged**. I've used the ViewHolder pattern in order to get a smooth behavior onScroll event of the listView. But because of updating the data set each time I get the bitmap in order to display the picture, the scroll is not smooth at all....
Here is the Async request which on its success callback I update the entire dataSet.

```
PsPicturesServices services = new PsPicturesServices();

        services.downloadPicture(listUrls.get(numProductAllProduct), new OnPicturesServicesListener() {

            @Override
            public void OnResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {

                allProducts.get(numProductAllProduct).setDefaultImageBitmap(bitmap);

                ((ProduitsListAdapter) allProductsList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();allProductsList.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                numProductAllProduct++;
                if(numProductAllProduct < listUrls.size())
                {
                    loadAllProductsPictures(listUrls);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void OnError(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

**allProducts** is the list associated to the adapter when it's first populated and when I get the bitmap I update the object accordingly thanks to an index. Then I update the whole dataset... 
The getView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ProductViewHolder viewHolder;


    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.produits_entretien_item_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ProductViewHolder();

        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
        viewHolder.productNameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productTitle);
        viewHolder.priceTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ProductViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Produit produit = getItem(position);

    if((Constants.CATEGORIE_LENTILLES_PAR_MARQUE).equalsIgnoreCase(GlobalVariables.getInstance().getCurrentRecherche().getProductCategorie().getNom())
            || (Constants.CATEGORIE_LENTILLES_PAR_PERIODE).equalsIgnoreCase(GlobalVariables.getInstance().getCurrentRecherche().getProductCategorie().getNom()))
    {

        if(produit.getDefaultImageBitmap() != null && produit.getDefaultImageBitmap() != null)
        {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(produit.getDefaultImageBitmap());
        }

        viewHolder.productNameTextView.setText(produit.getNom());
        viewHolder.priceTextView.setText(Float.toString(produit.getPrixTtc()));

    }
 return convertView;
```

Does someone see how could I do better to make the scroll smoother ? Thanks in advance....

Comment: what does `getView` look like?

Comment: smooth scrolling is often affected by how you design your list item's layout and your adapter's getView() method. you may want to post both of the code I mentioned.

Comment: I've updated my post guys !!! :)

Comment: I've tried to execute my async call without setting the bitmap and it smooth again, so the problem is really coming from the dataSetChanged called each time I get a new bitmap

Answer (score 0):

You can load an image into a row without calling notifyDataSetChanged(). The easiest way to do this would be to grab the child View for the image index from the ListView and set the bitmap directly on that. Rough code:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = ...;
int index = ...;
int childIndex = index - mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
ImageView view = mListView.getChildAt(childIndex).findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
view.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried already, I changed that method to the one that posted in my question